# First value in Bubble method shows huge negative number

Tags: c, sorting

It's my first post here. I'm new to this sort of thing.

I'm trying to learn the **bubble method**. Everything works fine except the first number always shows a complete random negative number. For example, i just ran the program and it says:
`-858993460, 2, 2, 3, 5,`  instead of
`2, 2, 3, 5, 8`  which is what it should say.
It uses srand to fill the array, so that I can test it continuously without having to input anything.

Here's the code, my main language is Spanish so if anyone from a Spanish-speaking country is seeing this feel free to answer en Español :)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
void randomArray(int[], int);
void mostrarArray(int[], int);
int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, array[5], cantElementos = 5, aux = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    randomArray(array, cantElementos);
    mostrarArray(array, cantElementos);
    for (i = 0; i < cantElementos; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cantElementos; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                aux = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nEl array arreglado es:\n");
    mostrarArray(array, cantElementos);
    return 0;
}
void randomArray(int array[], int cantElementos) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cantElementos; i++) {
        array[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }
}
void mostrarArray(int array[], int cantElementos) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cantElementos; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: `array[j + 1]` is an out-of-bounds access due to the range of your inner loop.

Comment: You can use `for (j = 0; j < cantElementos - 1; j++)` ... Or, use `for (j = 1; j < cantElementos; j++)` and use `j-1` and `j` for the `if`

Comment: @ChrisMM Thank you!! Solved it and now that i see what i should've wrote i understand the mistake. Thanks again, im impressed on how quick you guys answered!

Comment: One thing about working with C: If you have an array (which includes strings, which are just arrays of characters) and you have weird or wildly wrong garbage at the end of the array (like your -858993460), you've probably doing something that takes you out of array bounds.